# Как правильно составить запрос к базе данных с помощью Laravel Eloquent или raw sql?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

подскажите пожалуйста, я новичок в Laravel, и, возможно, не так силен в SQL.
У меня есть таблица категорий и связанные с ними посты. Я хочу вытащить все категории, но чтобы к каждой из них подхватились только по 4 поста, отсортированных по дате добавления.
Я пытался сделать следующим образом:

```
$categories = Category::query()->with(['posts' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4);
    }])
        ->get();
```

Но в таком случае запрашивается всего 4 поста, а не у каждой категории.

Comment: Стандартная задача - выбор N первых/последних записей в группе. ROW_NUMBER() в CTE.

Comment: `$query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4)->get();` ?